# "Path not found" error while trying to install Photoshop CS6 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine, playonlinux, winetricks, photoshop

I am trying to install photoshop cs6 in Ubuntu 14.04 using PlayOnLinux and while clicking the install button am getting an error "Path not found". I have googled a lot on this issue, and I couldn't fix this yet.

[Take a look at the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vU02.png)

Comment: Why C:\Program Files\Adobe is there in Location ?

Comment: @Rahul Thats the install location. C drive of wine. I tried with changing that also, still not working. So, the problem is not with that I guess